# Pandas: Handling Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

A certain dataframe, has a similar break with the one below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Elvis', 'Gerrard', 'Pitty'],
              'age': [22,23,24,25],
              'document': [111,222,333,4444]})
```

How can I make a filter to return only the rows where the values ​​in the document column are only 3 digits?

Comment: I usually do not care about the accept question op picked , however, you should not using apply in this situation , since it will slowing down the whole process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `log`

```
df.query('2 <= log10(document) < 3')

      name  age  document
0     John   22       111
1    Elvis   23       222
2  Gerrard   24       333
```

---

#### Expanded example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John', 'Elvis', 'Gerrard', 'Pitty'],
    'age': [22, 23, 24, 25],
    'document': [11, 222, 999, 1000]
})

df

      name  age  document
0     John   22        11  # 2 digit number
1    Elvis   23       222  # 3 digit number
2  Gerrard   24       999  # 3 digit number | edge case
3    Pitty   25      1000  # 4 digit number | edge case
```

Let's get only 3 digit numbers

```
df.query('2 <= log10(document) < 3')

      name  age  document
1    Elvis   23       222
2  Gerrard   24       999
```

Answer (score 3):

Try // which will return the divisor of 1000, since 3 digit so the divisor should be 0

```
df[df.document//1000==0]
Out[474]: 
      name  age  document
0     John   22       111
1    Elvis   23       222
2  Gerrard   24       333
```

---

We convert to `str` then count the `len`

```
df[df.document.astype(str).str.len().eq(3)]
Out[476]: 
      name  age  document
0     John   22       111
1    Elvis   23       222
2  Gerrard   24       333
```

Update

```
df[df.document.astype(str).str.split('.').str[0].str.len().eq(3)]
```

Comment: What about 2 digits? Would also appear in the `//` solution ;p Also,. what about floats in the `astype(str)` solution?

Comment: @rafaelc seems like you adding more edge situation . will update for u

Comment: `df[df.document.floordiv(100).between(1, 9)]`

Comment: @piRSquared: why don't you call between directly such as: `df[df.document.between(100, 999)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.document.apply(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for positive and negative numbers in the `document` column:

```
df[df['document'].abs().astype(str).str.len() == 3]
```